# How do I add QtDeclarative to the pkg-config list

Tags: 12.04, qt, pkg-config

I installed today the libqt5 and QtQuick development stacks.  In trying to also install the hsqml packages for Haskell, hsqml reports that QtDeclarative is not listed in pkg-config.  However, I have installed libqt5declarative5 and found both an i386 and x86_64 version of libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.1 on my filesystem.

So, how do I get pkg-config to add those files to the listing so that other applications can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, it would appear that the difference is that I have installed QT 5 in order to do development, and QtDeclarative has been subsumed into other components for QT 5.  The HsQML library is apparently designed for older versions of QT.  So the answer is that I should not be adding QtDeclarative to pkg-config at all, but should instead be looking to port HsQML to QT 5.